# Difference between IsRowGUID and UniqueIdentifier

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, types, field, guid

When creating a new Primary Key field, for a SQL server database in Visual Studios. I noticed that they type of the field can be uniqueidentifier. This can also be changed to nvarchar and int or bit. I also noticed though in the attributes of the field I can specify 'TRUE' for isRowGUID.

When Visual Studios creates an XSD definition automatically after importing the database (an .SDF file for this particular instance. AKA SQL compact) It automatically maps the type uniqueidentifier to the CLR type GUID. What advantages, if any, does setting the isRowGUID to true provide?

Any information or direction in this question is appreciated, as all previous efforts to gather infromation on this subject have yielded little to nothing.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://forums.asp.net/t/1248405.aspx

Comment: Yes similar but it still leaves to question "what is the gain of specifying a RowGuid if you have already assigned the Uniqueidentifier type to the field. The posts in the forum speak of the two options as if they were one and the same, but one can exists without the other indicating some sort of difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, rowguidcol/isrowguidcol tells SQL Server that the column is a unique row identifier much like identity does for an int column (uniqueness is enforced). It also forces a default value on the column much like identity sets the seed and increment values on an int column.  Just like there can be only one identity column for a table, there can be only one rowguidcol per table.

Rowguidcol enables you to refer to, access and/or identify this column using system stored procedures.  Also, SQL Server Replication can/will use the uniqueidentifier column marked as rowguidcol/isrowguidcol if available.  If not, replication will add the uniqueidentifier/rowguidcol to your existing table.  If you are planning on using SQL Server Replication, it might be advisable to add the column yourself as part of the design so at last you can name the column something useful.

Check out this link from Microsoft for more info ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191131(v=sql.105).aspx